# Python selenium click on button start

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How do I click auto start test? My code does not work

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
driver = wd.Firefox(executable_path='D:\Download\geckodriver\geckodriver')
driver.get('https://www.nperf.com')
import time
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("gaugeButton gaugeStartButton").click()
```

[image: Screenshot of webpage output with button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `button` you're trying to click is in an inner `iframe` so it is not visible to the driver. But you can switch to this `iframe`. Also instead of using `time.sleep()` you can use `WebDriverWait` so when the button is present and clickable it will click it. Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = wd.Firefox(executable_path='D:\Download\geckodriver\geckodriver')
driver.get('https://www.nperf.com')

iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("nPerfSpeedTest")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "gaugeStartButton")))
driver.find_element_by_class_name('gaugeStartButton').click()
# driver.switch_to.default_content()  # if you need to return to the main content
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to switch to the iframe in which the start test button is located:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("nPerfSpeedTest"))
```

Then you can click on the button:

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('gaugeStartButton')
btn.click()
```